# Any reliable method for transferring files between Android-based device and Windows-based computer?

Tags: files, mtp, file-sharing, motorola-moto-z2-play

From at least [Android 4.0](http://itfuckup.com/2014/09/27/android-and-a-shit-called-mtp/) to at least [Android 8.0](http://itfuckup.com/2018/06/02/the-mtp-protocol-a-catastrophic-failure/) (most likely Pie as well) we are forced by Google-Microsoft trust into using MTP as the only (?) files transportation method between Android-based device and Windows-based computer (if not count as pity, sad and dully methods as attaching files to e-mail messages).

For at least **five** years billions of users around the world are forced into using solution that is:

- extremely slow (transferring large files collections or huge files takes hours even on USB 3.1),
- extremely unreliable (device can stop responding even after sending just a few files),
- not working at all most of the time (device that stoped working may not "restart" and may not allow you to copy files even after dozens of unplug cable-plug it again  sequences).

[image]

(I can see above message after *each and every file* that I copy; I have to unplug and plug the USB cable again after copying *each single file*)

Questions:

1. *Supporting, OT and philosophic one*: What am I missing? Why we are forced into using this madness? Why nothing had been done for five years to resolve it?
2. *Main and real one*: Is there **any** other way? Any fast, reliable method of transferring files from Android-based device to Windows-based PC?

Described problem was tested on Windows 7 and Android 8.0, so not the newest ones, but still very widely used. And on the quite modern phone -- Motorola Moto Z2 Play -- but of course happnes on dozen other Android-based devices that I own and billions of Android-based devices other uses.

And, as stated in links given in first sentence, absolutely nothing had been done into resolving this problem for at least five past years. Is this some kind of sadistic way of understanding market and treating its customers, developed by Microsoft and Google or what?

Comment: Would transfers via [tag:adb] be an option? I use nothing else (MTP is a pain in the a**). There are also [some GUIs](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/network_admin_adb#group_947) available if you prefer.

Comment: @Izzy: I need to install ADB on any PC to which I want to transfer files from my Android-based devices. If there is no other alternative to sh\*ful MTP then I have no other option like this. BTW: Is there any reasonable source to explain why we are still forced to that dumb MTP? Some weird business agreement between Google and Microsoft that pains users a\*es?

Comment: @Firelord The linked question: (a) is 3+ years old, (b) targets Windows XP mainly (while I need solution for Windows 7/10) and (c) targets ICS as "the newest Android version" (while I need solution for 8/9 | Oreo/Pie). I would have serious problems calling such thing a duplicate. I would rather call that linked question a very, very out-dated solution that has nothing to do with current situation on the market. And my question directly linked to current situation on the market and asks for up-to-date options.

Comment: You can find some minimal installation stuff [here](https://android.izzysoft.de/downloads) (my site). And the dumb decision was because with UMS the card became unavailable to the Android system when mounted. Though I still don't get why the card *must* be available to the system. I'd prefer to have a choice at least. I don't install apps on the card, so that reason is gone for me. But as usual: don't overstrain a dumb user…